# How to trim a string to either specific character in a bash script

Tags: string, bash, trim

I want to trim a string from one character, the last `/`, to either `:` or `@`, which ever appears first. An example would be:

```
https://www.example.com/?client=safari/this-text:not-this:or_this
```

would be trimmed to:

```
this-text
```

and

```
https://www.example.com/?client=safari/this-text@not-this:or_this
```

would be trimmed to:

```
this-text
```

I know I can trim text in bash from a specific character to another character, but is there a way to trim from one character to either of 2 characters?

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep` like so: `grep -Po '^.*/\K[^:@]*'`

Examples:

```
echo 'https://www.example.com/?client=safari/this-text:not-this:or_this' | grep -Po '^.*/\K[^:@]*'
```

or:

```
echo 'https://www.example.com/?client=safari/this-text@not-this:or_this' | grep -Po '^.*/\K[^:@]*'
```

Output:

```
this-text
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-o` : Print the matches only, 1 match/line, not the entire lines.

The regex `^.*/\K[^:@]*` does the following:

`^.*/` : Match from the beginning of the string (`^`) all the way up to the last slash ('/').
`\K` : Pretend that the match started at this position.
`[^:@]*` : zero or more occurrences (greedy) of any characters except `:` or `@`. This matches either until the end of the line, or until the next `:` or `@`, whichever comes first.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)

**NOTE:**
This works with GNU `grep`, which may need to be installed, depending on your system. For example, to install GNU `grep` on macOS, see this answer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/357426/329079

Comment: hmm I'm getting a usage error with grep when I try this.

Comment: @ryan `grep -P` requires GNU grep, if you're on macOS, you won't have that by default.

Comment: @ryan I edited the answer and added the note re installing GNU `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

With a little Bash function:

```sh
trim() {
    local str=${1##*/}
    printf '%s\n' "${str%%[:@]*}"
}
```

This first trims everything up to and including the last `/`, then everything starting from the first occurrence of `:` or `@`.

In use:

```
$ trim 'https://www.example.com/?client=safari/this-text:not-this:or_this'
this-text
$ trim 'https://www.example.com/?client=safari/this-text@not-this:or_this'
this-text
```

Comment: This answer only uses Bash built-ins and therefore avoids `fork()+exec()` syscalls which is good for performance. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use sed: `sed -e 's,^.*/,,' -e 's,[:@].*$,,'`.

First `-e` command (`s/regex/replacement/`) removes text from the start to the last `/`, then the second `-e` removes from `:` or `@` to the end of the text.

```
echo 'https://www.example.com/?client=safari/this-text:not-this:or_this' | sed -e 's,^.*/,,' -e 's,[:@].*$,,'
this-text
```